# Weird issue with craft/setup command

Tags: craft3, composer

I have been trying to install Craft CMS on Windows.

I tried composer:

```
composer create-project craftcms/craft d:\temp\craft
```

After that when I try to `craft setup` there is a loop on the console which doesn't end.

[image: craft/setup screenshot]

When I try to run `craft install` the same thing happens, a loop but different text!

[image: craft/install screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the latest version of Craft on Windows. Will look into it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're running PHP 7.4.0.  I could reproduce it on 7.4.0 on Windows, but when I updated to PHP 7.4.2, the issue went away.

This appears to be a PHP 7.4.0 bug on Windows as evidenced by this Github issue for Yii: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/17782